# Call method without opening show view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method which I would like to run from a controller, this should be done by clicking a button, the issue that I have is that when I click on the specific line or item I get redirect to that item's view.

Here is the route that I have created:
`patch '/withdraw/:id', to: 'payments#withdraw', as: :withdraw`

This is the link_to line:
`<%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_path(pay), method: :post %>`

And this is the method, which is actually updating existing attributes:

```
def withdraw
 @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
 @payment.withdrawn = true
 @payment.amount_interest = @payment.amount * 1.1
 @payment.save
end
```

What do I need to change in order to get the desired result? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `remote: true` to the link.

```
<%= link_to 'Withdraw', withdraw_path(pay), method: :patch, remote: true %>
```

and add `head :ok` at the end of action:

```
def withdraw
  ..
  head :ok
end
```

Comment: Do I need to edit my route, as I am getting the following error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/withdraw/3")`

Comment: thanks for the response, when I click on the withraw `link_to`, I get an unending/non-terminating loop trying to retrieve the specified record:  `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: @MorezSA This is because you have a bug in your initial `withdraw` code. Probably you want `@payment.amount_interest = @payment.withdraw.amount * 1.1`. Now there is endless and senseless loop

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I have fixed it, it's `@payment.amount * 1.1`, it now works great.